# How to exclude a filetype with .gitignore except in the top-level?

Tags: git, gitignore

The way my project is set up all `.js` files are generated from other file types except the `.js` files in the top level of my repo.

How do I configure my .gitignore to ignore any `.js` file that is not in the top level of my repo?

I have tried

```
/**/*.js
```

and

```
**/*.js
!*.js
```

and several variations on those, but they seem to always just include or exclude all `.js` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*/**/*.js
```

(adding a fixed wildcard before the variable one) should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the next approach:

1. Ignore all js-files:

> *.js

2. Exclude ignoring of the top-level js-files:

> !/*.js

So the result `.gitignore` should contain next two lines in correct order:

```
*.js
!/*.js
```